# PHP wont connect to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I cant seem ton get a connection between this php script and my MySQL database. As far as I am aware this code is correct and should execute the query. The problem is with the connection on line 1. I'm just wondering does anyone know of any reason why this is not working, or am I making a really foolish mistake.

```
<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database_name");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
    {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $query = "INSERT INTO lat_long (uname, lat, lon) VALUES ('boo', 'boo', 'boo')";

    mysqli_query($con, $query);

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

EDITED: Here is the error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /var/www/project
>   /insertar.php on line 7

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: What are the types of your fields in `lat_long` table?

Comment: post your error! if you're not getting one, then turn error reporting on!

Comment: this is the error im getting... Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /var/www/project/insertar.php on line 7

Comment: I found nothing wrong you code. I think your credentials are wrong. Please check them. And please post the error

Comment: Looks to me that your php-installation has no support for mysqli compiled into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting a connection error, chances are your problem will be found on this line:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database_name");
```

Are you sure you have got the correct host address, username, password and name of your database schema?

You may also want to check that you have the mysqli php extension installed on wherever this database is being hosted.

Comment: And the mysqli php extension is installed on where your database is being hosted?

Comment: Correct answer from Toemouse, I didnt have the module installed. Thanks man